# Victory chart - layout issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs, victory-charts

I've this Victory chart:

```js
<VictoryGroup
  singleQuadrantDomainPadding={false}
  padding={0}
  domainPadding={{ y: 40, x: 40 }}
  height={150}
  data={[123, 312]}
>
  <VictoryArea
    labels={this.generateLabels}
    style={{
      data: {
        fill: "rgba(200,200,200, 0.2)",
        stroke: "yellow",
        strokeWidth: 2
      }
    }}
  />
  <VictoryScatter size={5} style={{ data: { fill: "yellow" } }} />
</VictoryGroup>
```

[image: Victory Chart]

It's available on this sandbox:
https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-layout-issue-mkrdy

Unfortunately, when only one data element is available, the chart does not layout very well. Only the yellow dot from the VictoryScatter is shown. Neither the grey area or label is shown.  How can I solve this?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You are using two charts here, a Scatter Plot and an Area Chart. When you only display one point in your Scatter Plot, your Area Chart can't possibly determine two points to start and stop an actual area. You can see this as an area that's 0px wide (it starts and stops at the same exact position.

You could *fake* an area with a Bar Chart under your single point like this :

`<VictoryBar barWidth={5} style={{data: {fill: "rgba(200,200,200, 0.2)"}}}/>`

And display it whenever `data.length === 1`, it would look like this :

https://codesandbox.io/s/victory-layout-issue-jmpew

You'll also notice that I put the labels on the `<VictoryScatter />` and not on the `<VictoryArea>`, so your second chart (with a single point) now displays the label correctly.

Like this :

```
<VictoryScatter
    labels={this.generateLabels}
    size={5}
    style={{ data: { fill: "yellow" } }}
/>
```